# first item in matrix won't left align

Tags: matrices

I am trying to write the Levenshtein Formula in LateX.
However, the following problem occurs:

```
\begin{equation}
    lev_{a,b}(i,j)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
    max(i,j) & if min(i,j)=0, \\ 
    min\left\{\begin{matrix}
    lev_{a,b}(i-1,j)+1\\ 
    lev_{a,b}(i,j-1)+1)\\ 
    lev_{a,b}(i-1,j-1)+1_{a_{i}\neq b_{j}})
    \end{matrix}\right. & otherwise. 
    \end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation}
```

The text `max(i,j)` will show in the middle of it's lane, not aligned nicely at the left, as seen in this picture:

[image: the max(i,j) should be above the first min]

What i am hoping to achieve is that `max(i,j)` will appear above the first occurence of `min`, so more the left of the open bracket.

Does anybody know have do achieve this?

Kind regards!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `array` environment, which works basically like the `tabular` environment, but in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    lev_{a,b}(i,j) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
    \max(i,j) & \text{if } \min(i,j)=0, \\[2mm] 
    \min\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
    lev_{a,b}(i-1,j)+1\\ 
    lev_{a,b}(i,j-1)+1\\ 
    lev_{a,b}(i-1,j-1)+1_{a_{i}\neq b_{j}}
    \end{array}\right. & \text{otherwise}. 
    \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]
Also, I would suggest to write the text as text, even if it's in an equation, and to use the commands `\max` and `\min` to write both of these words upright, as operators.

Comment: Ah that indeed does the trick, i got lost in the matrix environment and did not realise an array could also work. Thanks for the additional tips as well! Looks way better

Answer (score 4):

You can nest `cases`; a generous space between the two parts is needed.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\lev}{lev}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\lev_{a,b}(i,j)=
\begin{cases}
\max(i,j) & \text{if $\min(i,j)=0$,} \\[2ex]
\min\begin{cases}
  \lev_{a,b}(i-1,j)+1\\
  \lev_{a,b}(i,j-1)+1)\\
  \lev_{a,b}(i-1,j-1)+1_{a_{i}\neq b_{j}})
\end{cases} & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Also, “lev” should be treated as an operator like `\max` and `\log`.

[image]

You may want to consider a different layout, though.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\lev}{lev}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\lev_{a,b}(i,j)=
\begin{cases}
\max(i,j) & \text{if $\min(i,j)=0$,} \\[2ex]
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}l@{}}
\min\{ & \lev_{a,b}(i-1,j)+1,\\ 
       & \lev_{a,b}(i,j-1)+1),\\ 
       & \lev_{a,b}(i-1,j-1)+1_{a_{i}\neq b_{j}})\}
\end{array} & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

you can use `matrix*` environment, which is defined in the \mathtools` package. It rnable to define alignment of matrix cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    lev_{a,b}(i,j) = \left\{
\begin{matrix*}[l]
    \max(i,j)           & \text{if } \min(i,j)=0, \\[2mm]
    \min\left\{\begin{matrix*}[l]
    lev_{a,b}(i-1,j)+1\\
    lev_{a,b}(i,j-1)+1\\
    lev_{a,b}(i-1,j-1)+1_{a_{i}\neq b_{j}}
        \end{matrix*}\right.    & \text{otherwise}.
    \end{matrix*}\right.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply nest a `cases*` environment in another `cases*`? I also defined `lev` as a math operator, to have it typeset in roman characters, with the proper spacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\lev}{lev}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \lev_{a,b}(i,j) =
\begin{cases*}
    \max(i,j) & if $ \min(i,j)=0 $, \\[1ex]
    \min\begin{cases*}
    \lev_{a,b}(i-1,j)+1\\
    \lev_{a,b}(i,j-1)+1\\
    \lev_{a,b}(i-1,j-1)+1_{a_{i}\neq b_{j}}
        \end{cases*} & otherwise.
    \end{cases*}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]